# Why is this approximate solution correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the following differential equation

$$ y''=-y + \alpha y |y|^2, $$

where $y=y(x)$ is complex in general and $\alpha$ is a real constant such that the second term is small compared to $y$ ($||^2$ is the absolute square). Numerically I find that a good approximation for this is found by taking the solution for $\alpha=0$, which is $ae^{ix}+be^{-ix}$ (with $a$ and $b$ determined by the initial conditions) and applying a little shift to the exponents: $ae^{i(1+\Delta_a)x}+be^{-i(1+\Delta_b)x}$, where $\Delta_a=-\alpha(|a|^2+2|b|^2)/2$ and $\Delta_b=-\alpha(2|a|^2+|b|^2)/2$.

I want to find a simple justification for this approximate solution. My attempt so far is this: assuming the solution $ae^{i(1+\Delta_a)x}+be^{-i(1+\Delta_b)x}$, and inserting it in the differential equation, we find (neglecting the $\Delta^2$ terms, and expanding the absolute square):

$$\Delta_a ae^{i(1+\Delta_a)x}+\Delta_b be^{-i(1+\Delta_b)x}=-\alpha/2 \bigg [ (|a|^2+2|b|^2)ae^{i(1+\Delta_a)x} + (2|a|^2+|b|^2)be^{-i(1+\Delta_b)x} +ab^*ae^{i(3+2\Delta_a+\Delta_b)x}+ba^*be^{-i(3+\Delta_a+2\Delta_b)x}  \bigg ]$$

By matching the exponentials of same power, we directly find the expression of the $\Delta$s. However there are those two (roughly-) third power terms left, that seem to indicate at first that the assumed form is not correct (because these are not small compared to the first two terms). And yet the $\Delta$s found in this way give a very good approximation. (You can choose initial conditions such that the last two terms are small compared to the first two, but my approximate solution is good even when this is not the case.)

How can we somehow disregard the last two terms? Or can we justify the $\Delta$s in a different way?

Comment: Your frequency 3 terms are not correct, the exponents should be $i(3+2Δ_a+Δ_b)x$ and $-i(3+Δ_a+2Δ_b)x$. Now you are forced to put similar frequency 3 terms in the ansatz for $y$, which get a factor of about $-8$ on the left side, with coefficients $\sim \alpha$. But these mix with the opposite frequency 1 terms to give additional frequency 1 terms on the right side. For real-valued $y$ the $Δ$ are all the same, I'm not sure if that carries over to the complex case.

Comment: You are right about the exponents, I just edited. Adding frequency 3 in the ansatz would also generate even higher frequencies on the right hand side that would have no matching terms in the left hand side right? As my ansatz works very well I suspect that there must be a way to justify it as it is...

Comment: Yes, but look at it in the approximation way. In order 0 you need not do anything. In order 1 you have to use all the terms turning up that are order 0, and the coefficients of the frequency 3 terms in $y$ are such. The next would be frequency 5 which should have coefficients of order $\alpha^2$ or even $\alpha ^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, due to the non-linear perturbation the frequencies will mix, and the base frequency also gets perturbed. You get terms with frequency about 3 on the right side that have coefficients of order $O(\alpha^1)$.  Neglecting them would mean to reduce the approximation order to zero and you would be back at the unperturbed equation. Thus you have to compensate these terms on the right side by adding corresponding frequency 3 terms to $y$ and thus to the left side.

This will also lead to terms of up to frequency 7 on the right side, but the coefficients there will have order 2 or 3 in $\alpha$, thus they can be ignored if the whole equation is considered only to first order, with a residual that is $O(\alpha^2)$.

So
$$
y = a_3e^{i(3+2Δ_a+Δ_b)x}+a_1e^{i(1+Δ_a)x}
+b_1e^{-i(1+Δ_b)x}+b_3e^{-i(3+Δ_a+2Δ_b)x}
$$
and for the terms it makes more sense to use a table from the start
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{frequeny}&\text{combination} (y,y|\bar y)&\text{coeff. left}&\text{coeff. right}\\
\hline
1+Δ_a&(1,1|1)&-2Δ_a&|a_1|^2 a_1 \\
&2(1,-1,-1)&&2|b_1|^2a_1\\
&2(3,-1|1)&&2a_3b_1\bar a_1\\
\hline
-1-Δ_b&(-1,-1|-1)&-2Δ_b&|b_1|^2 b_1\\
&2(1,-1|1)&&2|a_1|^2b_1\\
&2(-3,1|-1)&&2b_3a_1\bar b_1 \\
\hline
3+2Δ_a+Δ_b&(1,1|-1)&-8-3(2Δ_a+Δ_b)&a_1^2\bar b_1 \\
&2(3,1|1)&&2a_3|a_1|^2  \\
&2(3,-1|-1)&&2a_3|b_1|^2  \\
\hline
-3-Δ_a-2Δ_b&(1,1|-1)&-8-3(Δ_a+2Δ_b)&b_1^2\bar a_1 \\
&2(-3,1|1)&&2b_3|a_1|^2  \\
&2(3,-1|-1)&&2b_3|b_1|^2  \\
\end{array}
There are further terms in these frequencies that combine two or more factors of frequency 3, which surpasses the approximation order in the coefficients.

So in comparing coefficients of the same frequency we get
\begin{align}
-2Δ_aa_1 &= \alpha ((|a_1|^2+2|b_1|^2) a_1 + 2a_3b_1\bar a_1)\\
-2Δ_bb_1 &= \alpha ((2|a_1|^2+|b_1|^2) b_1 + 2b_3a_1\bar b_1)\\
-(8+3(2Δ_a+Δ_b))a_3 &=\alpha (a_1^2\bar b_1 + 2a_3(|a_1|^2 + |b_1|^2))\\
-(8+3(2Δ_a+Δ_b))b_3 &=\alpha (b_1^2\bar a_1 + 2b_3(|a_1|^2 + |b_1|^2))\\
\end{align}
So in the lowest order,
\begin{align}
a_3 = -\frac{\alpha}{8}a_1^2\bar b_1\\
b_3 = -\frac{\alpha}{8}b_1^2\bar a_1\\
\end{align}
which then reduces the first two equations in only their first-order terms to the form you already found.

Using all the terms in the table would give you the approximation in $O(\alpha^3)$, but would need the frequency 5 terms to balance. In conclusion
$$
y = -\frac{\alpha}{8}a_1^2\bar b_1e^{i(3+2Δ_a+Δ_b)x}+a_1e^{i(1+Δ_a)x}
+b_1e^{-i(1+Δ_b)x}-\frac{\alpha}{8}b_1^2\bar a_1e^{-i(3+Δ_a+2Δ_b)x}
$$
where
$$
Δ_a=-\frac{\alpha}{2}(|a_1|^2+2|b_1|^2)\text{ and }
Δ_b=-\frac{\alpha}{2}(2|a_1|^2+|b_1|^2).
$$

Comment: Thank you for looking in details. Adding the frequency 3 terms in the ansatz does solve it indeed. This adds a surprisingly small correction though, it is frustrating that there is no more elementary approach to quickly show that frequency 1 is good enough.